# Functions on nowhere dense sets

Tags: general-topology

I was working on the following problem:
"Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces such that $X$ is complete. Show that if $\mathcal F$ is a family of continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ such that $\mathcal F(x)$ is a bounded subset of $Y$ for each $x$ in $X$, then there exists a nonempty open subset $U$ of $X$ such that $\mathcal F(U)$ is a bounded subset of $Y$."

Now, the result is trivial except for when $X$ is nowhere dense. In fact, if $X$ has an interior point, we can take $U$ has one of its balls wholly contained in $X$. The fact is that I cannot grasp the relation between continuous function and nowhere dense sets.
I made many assumptions but none of them seems to work out; these are the two I think might work better:

1. I know that the image of the family of functions is a bounded subset, thus I can extract an open subset out of it and then I can observe that if $V$ is an open subset of $Y$, then $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $X$.
2. I can use the fact that for each $x$ in $X$ I can find an $r$ so that the ball consists of only $x$ together with the fact that if the function is continuous we have that $d(x_0,x_1)<\epsilon$ implies $p(f(x_0),f(x_1))<\delta$, where d and p are respectively the metrics on $X$ and $Y$.

I am not very interested in the problem itself, but I would like to find a link, a connection between a nowhere dense space and a continuous function of its.

Comment: " if X
 has an interior point, we can take U
 has one of its balls wholly contained in X": No. We only know that $\mathcal F(x)$ is bounded, not that $\mathcal F(B)$ is bounded for a ball $B.$

Comment: Your points 1 and 2 are extremely confuse, e.g. "the image of the family of functions is a bounded subset", "the ball consists of $x$
 and nothing else", "we have that $d(x_0,x_1)$ implies $p(f(x_0),f(x_1))$".

Comment: I tried correcting the text. I'm sorry but I rarely write formally so I'm used to overlooking way too many things.

Comment: For your comment about the fact that F(B) is not bounded, I would say that if F(X), not thr single point but rather the whole set, is bounded, F(B) is so too.

Comment: F(X) is of course not assumed to be bounded.

Comment: What about my first point? I really don't find anything wrong with the argument but I don't find it rigorous too.

Comment: Sorry but I give up, for me both point 1 and 2 have neither head nor tail.

Comment: Apart from the points Anne already mentioned: have you thought about what it means that $X$ is nowhere dense? I would say, that's the really trivial case!

Answer (score 1):

> Now, the result is trivial except for when $X$ is nowhere dense. In fact, if $X$ has an interior point, we can take $U$ has one of its balls wholly contained in $X$.

$X$ can't be nowhere dense. Remember, $X$ is the *entire metric space*! The closure of $X$ is the whole of $X$. The interior of the closure of $X$ is also the whole of $X$! Thus every point in $X$ is an interior point. Also, every ball in $X$ is wholly contained in $X$, because there are no points "outside of" $X$. $X$ *is* the whole metric space.

> I know that the image of the family of functions is a bounded subset...

I presume you're saying that $\mathcal F(X) := \{ f(x) : x \in X, f \in \mathcal F \}$ is a bounded subset of $Y$. This is not one of the assumptions in the framing of the problem, and it is not necessarily true. Also, if this statement were true, then the problem becomes trivial, because we could just take $U = X$. (Yes, $X$ is an open subset of itself.)

> ... thus I can extract an open subset out of it and then I can observe that if $V$ is an open subset of $Y$, then $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $X$.

I would phrase this like so: For *every* $f \in \mathcal F$, if $V$ is an open subset of $Y$, then $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $X$. This statement is true, but not for the reason you give. This statement is true because each $f$ is assumed to be *continuous*. We're going to use this statement to solve this problem. (See below.)

> I can use the fact that for each $x$ in $X$ I can find an $r$ so that the ball consists of only $x$.

It sounds like you're saying that for each $x \in X$, there exists an $r > 0$ such that $B_r(x) = \{ x \}$. In other words, each $x \in X$ is an isolated point in $X$. This is false. For example, if $X = \mathbb R$, then $X$ contains no such isolated points.

> ... together with the fact that if the function is continuous we have that $d(x_0,x_1)<\epsilon$ implies $p(f(x_0),f(x_1))<\delta$, where d and p are respectively the metrics on $X$ and $Y$.

Firstly, I would suggest tweaking the notation. Maybe use $d_X$ and $d_Y$ as the metrics on $X$ and $Y$ respectively. As written, the $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are the wrong way round. Also, the statement doesn't make sense without phrases like "for all" and "there exists". The statement should read: "If $f$ is continuous at some $x_0 \in X$, then for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $d_X(x_0, x_1) < \delta$ implies $d_Y(f(x_0), f(x_1)) < \epsilon$ for all $x_1 \in X$.

I'd also remark that your point number 1 and point number 2 provide alternative definitions of continuity. Point number 1 uses the open sets approach, whereas point number 2 uses the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ approach. The two definitions are equivalent, so we only need one of them. I suggest we go with the definition in your point number 1, since that's easier to work with.

---

I'll outline a possible approach to solving this problem, based on the *Baire category theorem*.

Pick an arbitrary point $y_0 \in Y$. For each $n \in \mathbb N$, define
$$ U_n := \{ x \in X : d_Y(y_0, f(x)) > n \text{ for some } f \in \mathcal F \}.$$

- Show that each $U_n$ is open. [Observe that $U_n = \bigcup_{f \in \mathcal F} f^{-1}(\{ y \in Y : d_Y(y_0, y) > n\})$, and use the fact that every $f \in \mathcal F $ is continuous. The definition of continuity in your point number 1 is useful here.]
- Show that $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} U_n = \emptyset.$ [For each $x \in X$, we know that $\mathcal F(x) := \{ f(x) : f \in \mathcal F \}$ is a bounded subset of $Y$. Use this to infer for each $x \in X$, there exists an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $x \notin U_n$.]
- Deduce that there exists some $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $U_n$ is not dense in $X$. [If it were the case that all the $U_n$'s were dense in $X$, then what would the Baire category theorem tell you about $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} U_n$?]
- Conclude that there exists a non-empty open subset $U \subset X$ such that $\mathcal F (U)$ is bounded. [If $U_n$ is not dense in $X$, then *by definition*, there exists a non-empty open $U \subset X$ such that $x \notin  U_n$ for all $x \in U$. By definition, $\mathcal F(U) := \{ f(x) : x \in U, f \in \mathcal F \}$, so...]

By the way, I think there's a minor error in the statement of the exercise. We need to assume that $X$ is *non-empty*. Think about how this is implicitly used in our solution.

Comment: You've explained really well. Thank you for your time

Comment: No problem! Was a pleasure.

Comment: +1 for your unwavering benevolence.

Answer (score 1):

I already commented most inconsistencies and edited the post to correct some of them (sometimes twice, when you insisted on replacing "$\mathcal F(x)$ for all $x$" with "$\mathcal F(X)$ for all $x$" in the boundedness hypothesis). I did not mention one more problem in your point 2: this smells like a definition of continuity (with the usual epsilon-delta reversed) but quantifiers are missing.

I was ready to type a solution when I saw Kenny's. Mine is similar but never mind, let me edit it.

We must assume $X,Y\ne\varnothing.$ Fix some $y\in Y$ and for every $n\in\Bbb N,$ let $\bar B_n$ be the closed ball with center $y$ and radius $n,$ and let
$$F_n:=\{x\in X\mid\mathcal F(x)\subset \bar B_n\}.$$

The assumption "every $\mathcal F(x)$ is bounded" rewrites:
$$X=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n.$$
The assumption "every $f\in\mathcal F$ is continuous" implies that every $f^{-1}(\bar B_n)$ is closed, hence
$$\forall n\in\Bbb N\quad F_n=\bigcap_{f\in\mathcal F}f^{-1}(\bar B_n)\text{ is closed.}$$

Therefore, by [Baire's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) (since $X$ is a non empty complete metric space), at least one $F_n$ has a non empty interior, i.e. there exists a natural number $n$ and a non empty open subset $U\subset X$ such that $\mathcal F(U)\subset F_n,$ q.e.d.

Comment: Thank you a lot, you've been of great help